# Java Swing - how to add image in north of Jpanel

Tags: java, image, swing

I want to add image in `NORTH` part of my `JPanel`, but it doesnt work.
What should i do?

```
class PanelGlowny extends JPanel 
{    
    PanelGlowny()
    {        
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        ImageIcon imageurl = new ImageIcon("logo.jpg");
        Image img = imageurl.getImage();
        this.add(img, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }
}

public class Formatka extends JFrame 
{    
    private PanelGlowny panel = new PanelGlowny();

    public Formatka()
    {    
        ...
        add(panel);
    } 
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your directory structure ? Where are you keeping your images ? Do access your image by using `getClass().getResource("/logo.jpg")`, that's how you access `Application Resources`. Both the answers are too good :-) Are you using some IDE for making Swing Applications ? Hope this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) can help you more.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a working modification of your code. You should be able to run it as is. Essentially, you can't simply add the `ImageIcon` to the `JPanel`. You need to wrap it in a `JLabel` first.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test2
{
    public static class PanelGlowny extends JPanel
    {

        public PanelGlowny( )
        {

            this.setLayout( new BorderLayout( ) );

            // incorporated @nIcE cOw's comment about loading classpath resources
            URL url = getClass().getResource("logo.jpg")
            ImageIcon imageicon = new ImageIcon( url );
            JLabel label = new JLabel( imageicon );

            this.add( label, BorderLayout.NORTH );

        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( );

        frame.add( new PanelGlowny( ) );

        frame.setSize( 400, 400 );

        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

}
```

Comment: As @nIcE cOw noted, the problem is most likely that your `"logo.jpg"` image is not being found. Try providing a **absolute** path to your image as a first test. That should definitely work. Then use `getClass().getResource("logo.jpg")` like @nIcE cOw mentioned to get a `URL` which you can pass into the `ImageIcon` constructor.

Comment: Also, when you use `getClass().getResource("logo.jpg")` you need to make sure that the `logo.jpg` image is somewhere on your [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java))

Answer (score 2):

Create a new [`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#JLabel%28javax.swing.Icon%29) from your `ImageIcon` and add that to your `JPanel`.

Comment: I added it private JLabel adam;
    '
    PanelGlowny(){
        
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    ImageIcon imageurl = new ImageIcon("logo.jpg");
    //Image img = imageurl.getImage();
    adam = new JLabel(imageurl);
    this.add(adam, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    
    }'

But it doesnt show any image.

Comment: @user1304098: please don't try to post code in a comment as it looses all formatting. Instead edit your original question and post your code there, then place a comment here letting us know you've done this. Jeffrey's answer is correct (1+), so if your attempt to use it fails, you've got a bug and will need to show the well formatted code above in your original question.