# Java Swing - why cant I add image to Jpanel?

Tags: java, image, swing

I dont know why I cant add image to my JPanel
i use code:

```
class PanelGlowny extends JPanel {

    private JLabel adam;
    private JButton henryk;

    PanelGlowny(){

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        ImageIcon imageurl = new ImageIcon("logo.jpg");
        //Image img = imageurl.getImage();
        adam = new JLabel(imageurl);
        add(adam, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        henryk = new JButton();
        add(henryk, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
}
```

Image is in the same folder as class, but if I use url to image it also do not add anything.
This code adding button, but do not add image :(

The problem is probably with my JDE, or Sandbox or sth like this, because code should be fine.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you have that image in your classpath. And if it is not working , is it throwing an exception ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, and as i told i tried also with URL.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997578/java-swing-how-to-add-image-in-north-of-jpanel (see my answer there which also answers this question)

Comment: ulmangt nope. In my previous question i had problem with code. Now the problem is probably with JDE, Sandbox or sth like this, because this code work on anodher computers.

Comment: If you provide an absolute path to the image does the code work?

Comment: *"probably with JDE"* I've never heard the abbreviation JDE.  DYM JRE, IDE..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
imageurl = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("logo.jpg"));
```

Check [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) tutorial.

**EDIT**: loading remote image

Try that to load your image from web:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "", 
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
            new ImageIcon(new URL("http://marinerczarter.pl/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/headers/path.jpg")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Failure", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work. I think the problem is isn't with code, but with my JDE, Java Sandbox or something. But i am updated it to newest version and it still doesnt work.

Comment: What does not, do you get an exception? Is image in same package with your class? If not, use relative paths in `getResource()` and start with `/`

Comment: It is, and i also use paths. If i put C:\\mariner.jpg, or http://marinerczarter.pl/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/headers/path.jpg it also doesnt work.

Comment: @user1304098 , check if you see the image loaded from your url.

Comment: and when you run above `main()` that opens your image in `JOptionPane`?